# urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request (bottlenose)

Tags: python, api, amazon-web-services, bottlenose

After installing bottlenose and getting my API keys and associate tags I tried following the instructions in this guide: https://github.com/lionheart/bottlenose

(I have removed my api keys)

This is the error I am getting:

```
>>> import bottlenose
>>> amazon = bottlenose.Amazon(AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY, AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG)
>>> response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="B007OZNUCE")
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#2>", line 1, in <module>
response = amazon.ItemLookup(ItemId="B007OZNUCE")
File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 265, in __call__
{'api_url': api_url, 'cache_url': cache_url})
File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\site-packages\bottlenose\api.py", line 226, in _call_api
return urllib2.urlopen(api_request, timeout=self.Timeout)
File "C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 162, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File"C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 471, in open
response = meth(req, response)
File"C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 581, in http_response
'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
File"C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 509, in error
return self._call_chain(*args)
File"C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 443, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File"C:\Users\Windows\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\lib\urllib\request.py", line 589, in http_error_default
raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you have the system clock correctly configured.

I have the same problem and I fixed it changing the date and time to the correct one.

Comment: I checked under Ubuntu the time and set my location but no change did show up.

Answer (score 0):

You have to provide the value for keys

- **AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID**
- **AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY**
- **AWS_ASSOCIATE_TAG**

In order to get the keys you have to register on AWS

Comment: i have these keys. I removed them to make this post. I did not want to paste my keys here.

Comment: i tried with another example. I didn't get any error. Please check that item id is present

Comment: the item ID is present. I think the issue is with the associate tag. How can i fix this if this is the problem?

Comment: In my case I checked the three parameters and they're doing well via web using the scracthpad (my code using Ubuntu).